# how to send list object with list in it through parcelable

Tags: android, list, object, android-intent, parcelable

I'm not able to get list object which has another list in it through parcelable to another activity. Below is my code.

SnipDataEvents.java

```
public class SnipDataEvents implements Parcelable {

private String title,image,language,bookingUrl,infoUrl,genre;
private List<Venues> venuesList;

public SnipDataEvents(String title,String image,String language,String    genre,String bookingUrl,String infoUrl,List<Venues> list){
    venuesList = new ArrayList<>();
    venuesList.addAll(list);
    this.title = title;
    this.image = image;
    this.language = language;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.bookingUrl = bookingUrl;
    this.infoUrl = infoUrl;
    this.venuesList = list;

}


protected SnipDataEvents(Parcel in) {
    title = in.readString();
    image = in.readString();
    language = in.readString();
    bookingUrl = in.readString();
    infoUrl = in.readString();
    genre = in.readString();
    in.readTypedList(getVenuesList(),Venues.CREATOR);
}

public  static final Creator<SnipDataEvents> CREATOR = new Creator<SnipDataEvents>() {
    @Override
    public SnipDataEvents createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SnipDataEvents(in);
    }

    @Override
    public SnipDataEvents[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SnipDataEvents[size];
    }
};

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public List<Venues> getVenuesList() {
    return venuesList;
}

public String getBookingUrl() {
    return bookingUrl;
}

public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}

public String getInfoUrl() {
    return infoUrl;
}

public String getLanguage() {
    return language;
}

public void setVenuesList(List<Venues> venuesList) {
    this.venuesList = venuesList;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(title);
    parcel.writeString(image);
    parcel.writeString(language);
    parcel.writeString(bookingUrl);
    parcel.writeString(infoUrl);
    parcel.writeString(genre);
    parcel.writeTypedList(venuesList);


}
}
```

Venues.java

```
public class Venues implements Parcelable {
private String name;
//private List<String> showTimes;

public Venues(String name, List<String> showTimes) {
    //showTimes = new ArrayList<>();
    this.name = name;
    //this.showTimes = showTimes;
}

protected Venues(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    //showTimes = in.createStringArrayList();
}


public static final Creator<Venues> CREATOR = new Creator<Venues>() {
    @Override
    public Venues createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Venues(in);
    }

    @Override
    public Venues[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Venues[size];
    }
};

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

//public List<String> getShowTimes() {
// return showTimes;
//  }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(name);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putParcelableArrayList("snipdataevents",(ArrayList<SnipDataEvents>)snipDataEvents);
 intent.putExtras(bundle);
 startActivity(intent);
```

DetailActivity.java

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
snipDataEvents = bundle.getParcelableArrayList("snipdataevents");
```

when I run the code ,in DetailActivity.java bundle.getParcelableArrayList("snipdataevents") returns null

when I removed this

```
in.readTypedList(getVenuesList(),Venues.CREATOR);
```

and

```
parcel.writeTypedList(venuesList);
```

aboves lines in SnipDataEvents.java 
then run, bundle.getParcelableArrayList("snipdataevents") returns list.

I don't know whats wrong with the code...
Can anyone please help??

Comment: I don't know but I suggest  lib https://github.com/johncarl81/parceler.It's easy to use

Comment: I can't use third party :(

Answer (score 0):

You can done this one by **Passing ArrayList** in form of **String**.

1. Add `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'` in **dependencies** block **build.gradle**.
2. Click on **Sync Project** with **Gradle** Files

## SnipDataEvents.java

```
public class SnipDataEvents {

    private String title, image, language, bookingUrl, infoUrl, genre;
    private List<Venues> venuesList;

    public SnipDataEvents(String title, String image, String language, String genre, String bookingUrl, String infoUrl, List<Venues> list) {
        venuesList = new ArrayList<>();
        venuesList.addAll(list);
        this.title = title;
        this.image = image;
        this.language = language;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.bookingUrl = bookingUrl;
        this.infoUrl = infoUrl;
        this.venuesList = list;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public List<Venues> getVenuesList() {
        return venuesList;
    }

    public void setVenuesList(List<Venues> venuesList) {
        this.venuesList = venuesList;
    }

    public String getBookingUrl() {
        return bookingUrl;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public String getInfoUrl() {
        return infoUrl;
    }

    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }
}
```

## Venues.java

```
public class Venues {
    private String name;
    public Venues(String name, List<String> showTimes) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

## MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putExtra("snipdataevents", new Gson().toJson(snipDataEvents));
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

## DetailActivity.java

```
String json = getIntent().getStringExtra("snipdataevents");
snipDataEvents = Arrays.asList(new Gson().fromJson(json, SnipDataEvents[].class))
```